# Missing ADO.NET entity data model template from visual studio 2012 professional

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Missing ADO.NET entity data model template from Visual Studio 2012 Professional. I don't even have "Data" category from Visual Studio template category.

I modified the Visual Studio 2012 installation, and selected all the available packages to install. But even then no luck.

Comment: My problem was that I thought this was a project template, but it is an item template.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I did a search in C:\ProgramData\Package Cache for "eftools.msi"

There were three versions (from different beta/RCs I guess)

I picked the most recent and installed it.

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: This was really helpful from your side [Hainsey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/32055/hainesy). Just wanted to know, whether VS 2012 doesn't installs this eftools.msi by default, when we install VS 2012?

Comment: I don't have ProgramDATA Folder in my c: what to do ?

Comment: @Chlebta Do a search in all of C:\ I guess

Comment: @Hainesy I have Sloved this problem but now, I can't find "Code From dataBase" Or "Empty Code first Model..." in **ADO.net Entity Model Wizard**, I got "Generate From Database" and "Empty Model" Only.

Comment: This also worked for me. However, I had to do a "repair" as the product was installed, just not showing up.

Comment: Trying this resulted in "A newer version of this product is already installed.  Installation can not continue."

Answer (score 31):

Firstly you can add ClassLibrary in your Solution. 
Then, Add New Item to ClassLibrary and you can add Data>ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Comment: Gosh, I would have read this entry a few hours earlier. I would have spent a VS 2012 re-install. :S Thanks, for your answer mate! :)

Comment: +1 This should be the answer! Note that in VS 2013 you have to goto the project context menu and select Add->Component->Data->ADO .NET Entity Data Model.

Comment: Works for me on VS 2013, I did not have to install eftools.msi

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by going into project properties and changing the target framework. In my case, the default target framework for the project was 2.0 (no idea why - I would've expected 4.5 to be the default). I changed it to 4.5 and I was able to see the "ADO.Net Entity Data Model" option. I think it's all about having the correct EF tools installed for the CLR version that you are targeting.

Answer (score 5):

Close Visual Studio and then install "**Entity Framework Tools for Visual Studio**" from this location:

> ► **[Visual Studio Disk or installer folder]\packages\EFTools\EFTools.msi"**

I do it and I got the result.

---

You can also download this tool from [*here*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762).

Answer (score 1):

1. Press right click on an existing project
2. select "add" -> "New Item..."
3. Under "data" node you can select the "ADO.NET Entity Data Model"

[Here I found the solution](http://chanmingman.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/creating-ado-net-entity-data-model-in-vs-2012/)

Answer (score 1):

I found the EFTools.msi file in my packages folder, and run it then choose uninstall then run it again and choose install. After this reinstall, the template appeared.

Comment: Man, why is it not Accepted :-) . This solved my problem (Also in Visual Studio 2013) Thanks @PeterLiang

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the new EFTools6.1.3ForVS2013.msi, and then uninstalled it, it removes the ADO.net Entity Model option.
Microsoft never puts the old version back.
Thank you Hainesy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio Express 2013. If you have that problem, don't reinstall Visual Studio, you have to repair EF tools:

Search in `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache for "eftools.msi"`

Pick the most recent, run it and select repair.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today. But in my C:\ProgramData\Package Cache folder **there was only one eftools.msi** file. I installed it. Still the template was missing. Then I installed the same msi file again with **repair option**. Then the template appeared.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on add new item you will get general list of templates. "Visual c# " may be highlighted on left had side menu when you open it. From that you must click on "Data" menu. Now you can see ADO.NET Entity Data Model :)

Answer (score 0):

It succeeded me in a way just **downloaded** from given link https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40762 and **run for repair** the Entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the Project In Solution Explorer
2. Add > New Item > Data > ADO.NET Entity Data Model
   You can update [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40762)

[image]