# ODP.NET 1120320 Visual Studio 2012 Entity Data Model Wizard not responding

Tags: visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, odp.net

I'm working with Visual Studio 2012 and ODAC 1120320.
In this project I need 2 different edmx files since I've to work with 2 different DBs.

But I managed to import table only from the first schema, when I try with the second the Entity Data Model Wizard stops working and stays in Not Responding status for hours.

Can you help me to understand what is wrong?

Comment: How many tables are you trying to import when hangs? Can you try just importing a few? Is it hanging when it is just trying to display the table names? If so, connect in server explorer and in the connect dialog go to the Filters tab and set some filters to reduce the number of objects that would be displayed (for example, try "Starts with" A or something similar). Finally, you might try upgrading to ODTwithODAC121012

Comment: Thank you Christian, I disinstalled EF6 from program list, I reinstalled ODAC 1120320. I installed eftools.msi like explained by this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933767/missing-ado-net-entity-data-model-template-from-visual-studio-2012-professional and it worked. The problem was I had this installation of Entity Framework 6 in the program list which apparently was in conflict with the use of Entity Framework 5.